# Try to find out if my (use of google maps API services) calculations are correct?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am a nontechnical member (and idea leader) of a team that develop certain web application, so I am not very familiar with this area. I am asking this question here, because one or two responders here :) probably cross with this "problem" before. The problem for me is, that I dont know how to calculated the right number of requests or with other words "google maps API request and map loads usages of their services" when we would like to find out IF COORDINATE (which represent address) IS IN THE CERTAIN POLYGON OR NOT (polygons represent local areas, based on which we determin if address is in the area t or not).

My first findings were (i dont know if they are right?), that we will probably need (to find out if coordinate is in the polygon or not) to use GOOGLE MAPS JAVASCRIPT API (because we have web app and because we will get address that represents coordinate from user that is user who uses our app client-side) and containsLocation() FUNCTION from Geometry Library.

Now with all that, I assume that only "1 request" and "1 load map" through Google maps Javascript Api is taken?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps JavaScript API calculates only map loads. So your quota is limited to 25k daily map loads without Billing enabled and 100K daily map loads with Billing enabled.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

One map load corresponds to call `new google.maps.Map()`. If you call a function from geometry library it doesn't generate additional requests. Zoom, pan neither generate any additional request.

You will generate additional requests only if you use client side services like geocoding, directions, distance matrix or places (autocomplete, search or detail). In this case requests will be calculated against corresponding Web Service quota.

https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your time and willingness and give me this answer. It helps.